# Android robot RC app: how to make bluetooth paired devices list and password prompt

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

That is my Android robot remote control app:

[image: TRobotRC]

When you click the C - connect button a list with the bluetooth paired devices should appear. The list should consist of ListView objects and a click listeners. When you choose a robot to connect to, that menu should disappear and a password prompt should popup. Please suggest me the most simple and nice way to do that without intents.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I started using AlertDialog.Builder and adding the devices from this set: Set pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices(); using the builder method setItems().
I will need a HashMap because the dialog OnClickListener returns and integer value of the clicked item and i should associate the numbers with the mac addresses of the devices in order to connect.